# Highstock innacurate rendering of line data series

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I noticed that when I render a data a line graph, some of the data points are rendered higher or lower than the actual data values. This occurs when the chart width is smaller than normal (in my case, it occurs at a width of 358px).

This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/1038/) demonstrates the problem using highcharts-ng:

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
    "useHighStocks": true,
    "options": {

    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "type": "line",
            "data": seriesData,
            "threshold": null,
            "id": "series-1"
        },
        {
            "type": "bar",
            "data": seriesData,
            "threshold": null,
            "id": "series-2"
        }
    ]};
```

It renders the same series twice (once as a line, and the second time as a bar graph) to illustrate the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjdnw/1039/) is to turn off the dataGrouping feature in Highcharts:

```
 dataGrouping:{enabled: false}
```